# Audio Player Progress slider with timer displaying in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am new from iOS app development ,my requirement is need access the progress slider while playing , and show the proper start and end time , the player is working in url streaming , can you please help me to give some sample code , to fix this issue , Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970317/how-to-pause-an-audio-and-its-timer-slider-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

[image]Please find the below code. i have tested in Xcode 8 beta 2

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    IBOutlet UISlider       *sliderView;
    IBOutlet UILabel        *lblTimeInterval;
    AVAudioPlayer            *avpPlayer;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize strName;
@synthesize strTitle;
@synthesize trackCount;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //First comment added to Proj.
    //New Branch one is created by Team.

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)progrssSlider {
    avpPlayer.currentTime = sliderView.value;
}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {
    sliderView.value = avpPlayer.currentTime;

    lblTimeInterval.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",sliderView.value];

}

- (IBAction)pressPlayButton:(id)sender {

    //Read sound file from resource folder
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample.mp3" ofType:nil]];


    //Initialize AVAudioPlayer
    NSError *error;
    avpPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

    //Check Player is initialized
    if (!avpPlayer){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        [avpPlayer prepareToPlay];
        sliderView.maximumValue = [avpPlayer duration];
        sliderView.value = 0.0;

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [avpPlayer play];
    }


}

@end
```

Please define UILAbel to show Time, UISlider to Update Slider and Play button in Xib.

Hope this will work.